# How to get only one result from each group with SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, unique, distinct

I really don't know how to put a query for this task.

I need to get a time for the first row of each record in the table but every time when I have a group of same results I need to get the first one when it occurs and when signal is equal to 1.

I don't know how to explain it correctly but I will make an example and you'll see what I  mean.

Records:

```
ID| Time | Serial | Signal
 1| 10:59|   12   |   1
 2| 11:00|   12   |   1
 3| 11:01|   12   |   1
 4| 11:01|   13   |   1
 5| 11:02|   12   |   0
 6| 11:03|   12   |   0
 7| 11:05|   13   |   1
 8| 11:07|   12   |   1
```

So I need this result:

```
ID| Time | Serial | Signal
 1| 10:59|   12   |   1
 4| 11:01|   13   |   1
 7| 11:05|   13   |   1
 8| 11:07|   12   |   1
```

Comment: And do you have some working query? Post it if so, nevermind it is not correct, it's just a starting point

Comment: Not really, I only tried to get ones with the different serial and with signal that is equal to 1

Comment: How do you want to group by your data? the `12` and `13` appear twice in the sample data.

Comment: I want to group it by the time. So the first one that occurs I want it first and so on

Comment: @denonth, Why the `11:00 | 12`, `11:01 | 12` and `11:03 | 12` were removed. Do you need to remove only the first one and get all the others ordered by time?

Comment: @denonth Do you consider that if there was a 0 Signal, the next 1's are in new groups?

Comment: yes I consider if signal is 0 or serial is different than it is a new group

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your exact logic is not clear, from what I can gather you are looking to get each row where `signal` is 1 where the serial value changes from one time to another.

This can be done using a variable to track the value of the serial in the previous row (variable @t in my query below).

```
SELECT  ID, Time, `Serial`, `Signal`
FROM    (   SELECT  ID,
                    Time,
                    `Serial`,
                    `Signal`,
                    CASE WHEN `Serial` = @t THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS IsNew,
                    @t:= `Serial`
            FROM    T,
                    (SELECT @t:=0) t2
            ORDER BY Time
        ) t
WHERE   IsNew = 1
AND     `Signal` = 1
```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/45547/15)**

Answer (score 1):

You can do this way by generating a rank for consecutive `Serial` values and then by selecting only records having first rank. Try this query:

```
SELECT id, atime, serial, asignal
FROM (
      SELECT id,
             atime,
             asignal,
             IF(a.serial = @var_serial, (@var_rank:= @var_rank + 1),
                                        @var_rank := 1) AS rank,
             (@var_serial := a.serial) AS Serial
      FROM test_table a, (SELECT @var_rank := 1, @var_serial := 0) r
      ORDER BY id ASC
     )a
WHERE asignal = 1
      AND rank = 1;
```

## Example: [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d7cf6/1)

Answer (score 0):

I would start trying something like

```
SELECT * FROM tablename where Signal=1  GROUP BY Time ORDER BY Time ASC
```

Comment: But I only need unique ones that means only one first record with that serial number

Comment: @denonth But in that case, why do you have two of each 12 and 13 in your desired output?

Comment: @denonth 10:59 and 11:00 are also different times for serial 12.

Comment: yes but I only need first time of each unique group of serials that have signal = 1

Comment: @denont please define 'unique group of serials' it seems that something is missing in your question

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM your_table
WHERE id IN (
  SELECT MIN(id) FROM your_table
  WHERE Signal != 0
  GROUP BY Serial
)
```